# Using curl in Ansible with environment variable

Tags: ansible

I need to download a deb package, I use:

```
curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-5.1.1-amd64.deb
```

I have looked into http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/uri_module.html but unsure how to get this integrated.

Also I set proxy along with this. How can I do so in Ansible?

i am using now

```
- name: Download the 5.1.1 version of filebeat
  get_url:
      url: https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-5.1.1-amd64.deb
      dest: /home/ubuntu
  environment:
    http_proxy: http://{{ squid_proxy }}:{{ squid_port }}
    https_proxy: https://{{ squid_proxy }}:{{ squid_port }}
  validate_certs: no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather use [`get_url` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/get_url_module.html).

```
- get_url:
    url: https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-5.1.1-amd64.deb
    dest: /path/to/destination
```

It uses the proxy defined in `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables. If you don't have one defined for the current user (and it must be in the rc-files read for non-interactive sessions), you can add to the task:

```
- get_url:
    url: https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-5.1.1-amd64.deb
    dest: /path/to/destination
    validate_certs: false  # this might be required for HTTPS proxies with certificates not trusted by the client
  environment:
    https_proxy: https://my.proxy:8080
```

Also in case of HTTPS proxies with certificates not trusted by the downloading machine, you might need to add `validate_certs: false` to the `get_url` arguments.

Comment: along with proxy ?>?

Comment: how do i presever -L and -O flags?

Comment: the curl that i am using is having -L & -O option , so will there be any diff ?

Comment: so , if you look into the exact command that i am using `curl` it has two flags -L for the location of file on server which if changed, the curl will be redirected and -O , so if i use simply `get_url` of ansible , is there a way i can pass these 2 flags

Comment: You don't need to pass these two flags and Ansible does not use `curl` so that you can pass any flags. Moreover, you even don't need these two flags in your `curl` command - you don't have any redirection and you specify a filename. Even if you did not, Ansible would follow the redirection and download the file. You asked how to download the file with Ansible and I answered.

Comment: just something weird : msg: Unsupported proxy scheme: https. Currently ansible only supports HTTP proxies. i am using both https & http

Comment: Does your machine recognise correctly the certificate installed on the proxy? If not, add `validate_certs=false`.